# How to find Maxima and Minima of this function with two variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

> $$f(x,y) = x^3 + y^3 - 63(x+y) + 12xy$$
>   Find maxima and minima of this function.

I tried by taking partial derivative with respect to $x$,
which gives $$\frac{∂f}{∂x} = 3(x^2) - 63 + 12y$$
and by taking partial derivative with respect to $y$,
$$\frac{∂f}{∂y} = 3(y^2) - 63 + 12x$$

But by equating both equations to $0$, I am unable to get any value for $x$ and $y$ so that I can substitute them in double partial derivative to get maxima and minima. What steps to take ahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both derivatives equal to zero: then you have a system
$$
3x^2-63+12y=0 \\
3y^2-63+12x=0
$$

Isolate $y$ in the first equation and you get $y=-\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{21}{4}$. Substitute it in the second equation to get $3(-\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{21}{4})^2-63+12x=0$ or equivalently $$\frac{3}{16}x^4-\frac{63}{8}x^2+12x-63+3\cdot \frac{441}{16}=0\\
\frac{3}{16}(x^4-42x^2+48x-336+441)=0\\
\frac{3}{16}(x^4-42x^2+64x+105)=0\\
\frac{3}{16}(x-5)(x-3)(x+1)(x+7)=0$$
Now you can find the corresponding $y$'s and the solutions of the systems are $(-7,-7),(-1,5),(3,3),(5,-1)$
You just need to classify them now

Comment: And how did you get this ingenious factorisation?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I added some steps; the last one you can just use the rational root theorem

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the additive constants:
$$x^2+4y=y^2+4x\iff x(x-4)=y(y-4).$$
Rule out $x=4$ and $y=0$ as solutions so we can safely divide:
$$\frac xy=\frac{y-4}{x-4}.$$
Now use corresponding addition to get
$$\frac{x-y}{y}=\frac{y-4-(x-4)}{x-4},$$
that is 
$$\frac{x-y}{y}=\frac{x-y}{4-x},$$
from which either $x=y$ or $y=4-x$ follows.  Now proceed.

Answer (score 0):

you have two parabolas, $x^2 + 4 y = 21$ and $y^2 + 4x = 21.$

Add and you have the circle $$ x^2 + y^2 + 4 x + 4 y = 42  $$
or
$$  (x+2)^2 + (y+2)^2  = 50 $$

Subtract and you have $x^2 - y^2 - 4 (x-y) = 0,$ or
$$  (x-y)(x+y - 4) = 0  $$
which gives two perpendicular lines.

For the line $x=y,$ what do we get for $2(x+2)^2 = 50 \; ? \;$

Finally, you check for maxima with the second partial derivatives. There cannot be any global min or max, and I suspect the local critical points are saddles; I have not yet checked...